# After document.reload, messagePushed and urlLoaded events fired again

Tags: trigger.io

For both forge.event.messagePushed.addListener and forge.urlhandler.urlLoaded.addListener:

Whenever I fire a forge.document.reload() or document.location.reload() after the app was started using a push notification or urlhandler, either of those events will fire again.

I think trigger.io saves the notification/urlhandler data somewhere in the location in such a way that upon reload the app thinks that it was triggered again by either of those events.

Any way to clear that data?

Comment: Thanks for the report - we'll be deploying a fix for this in our next platform version: we were automatically triggering the last event when a new listener was added, without properly checking an event was actually outstanding.